# bug javascript or cache? or something else?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes i have changed code (using filezila) but page's behavior didn't change. CTRL+R or inkognito in browser dont help. **Only time can help here**.

**example:** Yesterday my script start work wrong(before i commented something and uncommented back then): jquery ui selectable didnt unselected on ctr+mouse_click. I shootdown PC and today all is alright. Miracle?

It happens pretty often.

**Thank you for minus 'karma', but i always create question like this for help someone who had same problem and he must know that he is not alone.**

p.s. my pc along time didnt shootdonw (only sleep mode), may be it is answer!? will see...

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache before you refresh the browser? StackOverflow won't help you on that

Comment: it's almost certainly caching. get a cache removing plugin for the browser you are using, also check if there is any serverside caching.

Comment: i think when i try inkognito = no cache here but its didnt help

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be cached pages, either by the server or the client.

You can confirm if the page is a cached copy by adding a time stamp or another note to the file.  Edit the script, and place the current time as comment in your code.  Then save changes/upload to server as required.

If the resultant page in your browser does not immediately show the time you entered earlier; then, the page is being cached.  To confirm if it's the browser, clear your browser cache and reload the page.  If the time stamp is not appearing still, then it is likely to be your server.

Check what kind of caching is enabled on the server and retest as above.

Comment: Once i add in broken code the alert. Alert start work but other script dont.

Comment: What you mean 'my server'? My provider or my site-side?!

Comment: @VitalikZenin If the code is updating without you having the clear the browser cache; then it's not a caching issue.  As there is a javascript error, I suggest you check the browser's javascript console for errors.

Comment: console and javascript are inseparable)